# Searching in a list of multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I am importing multiple dictionaries from a .txt file into my python file and then I have to search for a key ('name') in all of the dictionaries but my code only searches in the first dictionary and gives the results accordingly. I want to know if there is an easy way to handle this situation. Immediate help would be appreciated. The current code and the data in .txt file is presented below:

```
elif option == 's':
        if 'name' in open('data.txt').read():
            sea = input ("Type a menu item name to search for: ")
            file = open('data.txt', 'r')
            data = json.load(file)
            file.close()
            for index, line in enumerate(data):
                if sea.lower() in line['name'].lower():
                    print (index, line['name'])
                    main()
                else:
                    print ('No such item exist')
                    main()
        else:
            print ("The list is empty")
            main()
```

Dictionary:

```
[
  {
    "fat": 29,
    "carbohydrates": 45,
    "protein": 25,
    "sodium": 1040,
    "cholesterol": 75,
    "calories": 540,
    "name": "Big Mac"
  },
  {
    "fat": 47,
    "carbohydrates": 53,
    "protein": 33,
    "sodium": 1410,
    "cholesterol": 100,
    "calories": 760,
    "name": "Whopper"
  },
  {
    "fat": 80,
    "carbohydrates": 50,
    "protein": 650,
    "calories": 45,
    "cholesterol": 50,
    "sodium": 50,
    "name": "Icecream'"
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Most notably, the code you posted is not sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've made your first loop iteration to be the entire world: it looks at the first item in the list, reports success or failure on that search alone, and then calls the main program recursively (which is poor program construction, as well).

Try something with logic on this order:

```
found = False
for index, line in enumerate(data):
    if sea.lower() in line['name'].lower():
        print (index, line['name'])
        found = True

if not Found: 
    print ('No such item exists')
```

Finally, rather than calling **main()** wrap this in a **while** loop that tests the program's termination condition.

Comment: It is working but I am not sure about what condition to insert in the while loop. Can you please help me with that as well?

Comment: Good -- because your problem description says *nothing* about the program's termination condition; I was about to ask.  perhaps **while option != 'q'**?

Comment: Also, thanks for remembering to accept and answer.  Acceptances and votes (on answers and comments both) help to keep SO running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If using Python 3, you can use a [ChainMap](https://pymotw.com/3/collections/chainmap.html) which is designed for this very purpose. And probably more a more efficient algorithm than what your using.

I expect it's implemented as a "map of maps", where the top level map has a consolidated index of keys for each map, which point to the original entries in memory. Likely implemented in C. The important thing is that a change to  a member dict updates the index in the master dict. Otherwise, you'd have to do an iterative search of each dict. Then lookup couldn't optimized by sorting, etc. Some kind of watch can be used, e.g. if the underlying C object for dict is designed to check if it's part of chain map on changes, and notify.